# How do I bind multiple Combo Boxes to the same data set and allow only 1 box to select each piece of data?

Tags: c#, data-binding, combobox

Right now I'm maintaining 4 separate data sources and adding and removing items from each one as that item is selected/deselected in another comboBox.

```
AvailibleColors1 = new List<String>(new String[] { Resources.Red, Resources.Orange, Resources.Blue, Resources.White, null, });
AvailibleColors2 = new List<String>(new String[] { Resources.Red, Resources.Orange, Resources.Blue, Resources.White, null, });
AvailibleColors3 = new List<String>(new String[] { Resources.Red, Resources.Orange, Resources.Blue, Resources.White, null, });
AvailibleColors4 = new List<String>(new String[] { Resources.Red, Resources.Orange, Resources.Blue, Resources.White, null, });
```

This is for a simple game where players are selecting their colors and the idea is that a player should not even have the option to select a color already chosen by another player. My current method is functional but it's fragile (comboBox doesn't always update when items added/removed, not sure why) and inelegant. As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should use a single `Observable Collection` as your datasource. Bind it to all comboboxes. Now when a combobox gets selected, remove that item from OC so that other comboboxes applying it reflect that change.

[ObservableCollection<T> Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

Second Option

I asked same question. And this is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495342/how-to-enforce-distinct-selections-when-multiple-comboboxs-are-bound-to-a-commo). I haven't tried it so give it a try.

Comment: Wouldn't removing it from the OC remove it from the combo box where it's selected?